# Upload An Excel File in Classic ASP On Windows 2003 x64 Using Office 2010 Drivers

Tags: excel, asp-classic, upload, 64-bit, connection-string

So, we are migrating an old web app from a 32-bit server to a newer 64-bit server. The app is basically a Classic ASP app. The pool is set to run in 64-bit and cannot be set to 32-bit due to other components. However, this breaks the old usage of Jet drivers and subsequent parsing of Excel files.

After some research, I downloaded the 64-bit version of the new [2010 Office System Driver Beta](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C06B8369-60DD-4B64-A44B-84B371EDE16D&displaylang=en#filelist) and installed it. Presumably, this allows one to open and read Excel and CSV files.

Here's the snippet of code that errors out. Think I followed the lean guidelines on the download page:

```
Set con = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0;Data Source=" & strPath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 14.0;"""
con.Open
```

Any ideas why?

UPDATE: My apologies. I did forget the important part, the error message:

> ADODB.Connection error '800a0e7a'
>   Provider cannot be found. It may not
>   be properly installed.
>  
>   /vendor/importZipList2.asp, line 56

I have installed, and uninstalled/reinstalled twice.

Comment: The exact error message would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue a little while ago and I found out that there's actually a bug in the installer package for the ACE 14 driver.  The driver is being registered as "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0".  In my case I could get things to work just by changing my connection string to 12 as opposed to 14.

Evidence on the bug: [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/data/feedback/details/541090/access-database-engine-2010-installation-issue-to-use-with-ado-access-technology-to-access-data-from-jet-database-mdb-files?wa=wsignin1.0)

Answer (score 0):

It could be the Excel version in the Extended Properties parameter.  Excel 14 is for Office 2010.  While the driver may be Office 2010 I would presume your Excel documents are not.
Excel 2007 - v12
Excel 2003 - v8
From http://www.connectionstrings.com for Excel 2007:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";
```

You could try replacing the `ACE.OLEDB.12.0` with `ACE.OLEDB.14.0` to match the **driver** version.

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I understand it, the only Office drivers that come in a 64-bit version are the 2010 Beta drivers.

Comment: Your edit (with the error message) means that the problem is not in the connection string it's with the installation of the driver on the server - so my info is not helpful, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Here http://forums.asp.net/p/1128266/1781961.aspx is a suggestion to split your app into 32 and 64 bit components and transfer data via COM.  To quote:

> What you need to do is split your application into a 32 bit part and a 64 bit part, use COM interop to cross the 64/32 bit boundary. For instance, drop the code (just a simple class library compiled as 32 bit) that retrieves the Excel data into a COM+ (System.EnterpriseServices) as a "server type" application, and call that server methods from your 64 bit Windows service. This is exactly why System.EnterpriseServices are made for.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, finally, I realized that the error is that the connection string should be modified in 64 bit!

To get the right one, install visual basic 6 and drag the Microsoft data access control,through its wizard, open the file you want, and let it write the connection string to you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is "14" ("14.0") for Excel.  But "12" ("12.0") for ACE.

From this download:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=C06B8369-60DD-4B64-A44B-84B371EDE16D&displaylang=en

I found this snipplet:

**2.If you are an application developer using OLEDB, set the Provider argument of the ConnectionString property to “Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0”

◦If you are connecting to Microsoft Office Excel data, add “Excel 14.0” to the Extended Properties of the OLEDB connection string.**

HOWEVER!!!

The instructions from the download page seem to be wrong....causing some of this confusion.

From here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/686d8ebb-0da3-4f0c-bf16-9c650f8dcb32

//Quote //Paul P C
The instructions are incorrect. It should be Excel 12.0. I wish they would fix this mistake at the download site.
//End Quote

I have verified that this connection string works for me:
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\MyFile.xls';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;';"